# math formula for rating system

Tags: javascript, math, rating-system

I would like to know if there would be a better way to create my `stars` variable based on a percentage value.

All I need is to determine the rating 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc stars based on the percentage value.

I've done it with a switch statement, but wondered if there was a math formula that could do this?

Just seems a little long winded programmaticly to do it this way?

```
var stars = 0;

                switch (true) {
                    case score === 100:
                        stars = 5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 90:
                        stars = 4.5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 80:
                        stars = 4;
                        break;
                    case score >= 70:
                        stars = 3.5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 60:
                        stars = 3;
                        break;
                    case score >= 50:
                        stars = 2.5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 40:
                        stars = 2;
                        break;
                    case score >= 30:
                        stars = 1.5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 20:
                        stars = 1;
                        break;
                    case score >= 10:
                        stars = 0.5;
                        break;
                    case score >= 0:
                        stars = 0;
                        break;
                }
```

i'll admit my math skills are not very good (i'm dyslexic with numbers) so sorry if my question offends those that are strict about trying things yourself, but this is just frying my brain!

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Comment: Except for that last `case`, `score * 0.05` seems reasonable.

Comment: @David, I think the issue with that is OP seems to want to round down to multiples of `0.5` as per my answer. I assume the last `case score >= 100` was a typo and should have been `case score >= 0` otherwise it would not make any sense

Comment: @neelsg thank you it was indeed a typo! i will try your answer just now and come back :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
stars = Math.floor(score / 10) / 2
```

Comment: thank you so much, this works perfectly for this basic scoring ratio, and it's saved me near 40 lines of code :)

Answer (score 4):

please try this

stars = score > 100 ? 0: Math.floor(score * 0.1) / 2

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Math.floor(score * 0.1) / 2
stars = score > 100 ? 0: result
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!